# Node no guarda o ejecuta los cambios

Tags: nodejs, servidor, ide

Estoy programando con [un IDE online](http://codeanywhere.com) en node.JS, pero no me esta guardando los cambios que hago en el archivo principal de ejecucon, detengo y vuelvo a iniciar el servidor y mi pagina recibe lo mismo, ni siquiera me imprime en la consola del server un `console.log`, tendra que ver con el IDE?

Comment: Supongo que habrás *forzado* la recarga, ignorando la *caché*, pulsando `F5`, ¿ verdad ?

Comment: Si, hay alguna forma de que eso no pase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La equivocacion estaba en la caché del navegador.